# answer space in xsim

Tags: xsim

I am trying to use xsim to design a workbook for students, with a second version available for tutors. Therein will be exercises/questions/homework, however you want to call it, and their respective solutions.

From what I reviewed so far, [xsim](https://ctan.org/pkg/xsim), seems to be a mostly well-suited package to achieve this. However, there is one piece of information I could not find in the documentation: **How do I switch between an empty answer space/blank/box and the printed solutions?**

Ideally, I want a way for the answer space to take up exactly the phantom space of the typeset solution.

Attached you find a MWE of how I want it to work, however I wish to have the procedure automated.

The following MWE produces (notice the `solution/print = true`)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath}
\usepackage{xsim}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}



\DeclareExerciseEnvironmentTemplate{tcolorbox}
{%
\tcolorbox[
    beforeafter skip = .5\baselineskip ,
    title =
    \textbf{\GetExerciseName~\GetExerciseProperty{counter}}%
    \GetExercisePropertyT{subtitle}{ \textit{\PropertyValue}}%
    ]%
}
{\endtcolorbox}

\DeclareExerciseType{problem}{
exercise-env = problem ,
solution-env = answer ,
exercise-name = Problem ,
solution-name = Answer ,
exercise-template = tcolorbox ,
solution-template = tcolorbox
}

\xsimsetup{
    answer/print=true
}


\begin{document}
    \begin{problem}
        Show that $(\mathbb{R}, +, \cdot)$ is a field.
    \end{problem}

    \begin{answer}
        Let $a, b, c \in \mathbb{R}$ arbitrary. Then, we show the following properties:
        \begin{description}
            \item[Commutativity of addition]  $a + b = b+ a$.
            \item[Associativity of addition] $a +(b + c) = (a+b) +c$.
            \item[Additive identity] $0 \in \mathbb{R}$, and $a +0 = a $.
            \item[Additive inverse] for each $a \in \mathbb{R}$, there exists $-a \in \mathbb{R}$, sch that $a + (-a) = 0$.
            \item[Commutativity of multiplication] $a \cdot b = b \cdot a$.
            \item[Associativity of multiplications] $a \cdot (b \dot c) = (a \cdot b) \cdot c$.
            \item[Multiplicative identity] $1 \in \mathbb{R}$, such that $1 \cdot a = a$.
            \item[Multiplicative inverse] for each $a \in \mathbb{R}$, there exists $a^{-1}\in \mathbb{R}$, such that $a \cdot a^{-1} = 1$.      
            \item[Distributivity] $a\cdot (b + c) = (a \cdot b) + (a \cdot c)$. 
        \end{description}
        These are the necessary and sufficient properties of a field, hence $(\mathbb{R}, +, \cdot)$ is a field.
    \end{answer}
\end{document}
```

but I want **an empty box with the same dimensions when answers are disabled**.

[image: answer/print = true]

## Update

Ultimately, I ended up ditching `xsim`, persued a different path, and came up with my own alternative solution, which is detailed [in this other question and answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/616610/53868). However, it is still not an answer to this question.

## Update

One step later than ultimately, I retuned to using `xsim`. See my answer with the solution below.

Comment: IIRC at _least_ one of the example documents that comes with the `xsim` package has a solution for the question.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to these examples, I didn't notice them before. I believe I found a way to make work what I wanted to achieve, but I'm under pressure setting up my exercises now. Once done, I will add my solution as an answer myself.

Comment: While large parts of what I wanted are covered in your examples, a tiny bug prevents me from fully implementing my desired behaviour (bug report: https://github.com/cgnieder/xsim/issues/90).
If you know a short fix, that would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the meantime I have come up with an answer, however this answer depends on the version of `xsim` in use.

### xsim < v0.19b

See the updated MWE for example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath}
\usepackage[]{xsim}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\xsimsetup{
    solution/print = true,
}

\SetExerciseParameters{exercise}{
    exercise-name = \XSIMtranslate{exercise},
    solution-name = \XSIMtranslate{solution},
    exercise-template = exercise,
    solution-template = solution,
    counter=section,
}



\DeclareExerciseEnvironmentTemplate{exercise}
{%
\tcolorbox[
    beforeafter skip = .5\baselineskip ,
    title =
    \textbf{\GetExerciseName~\GetExerciseProperty{counter}}%
    ]%
}%
{%
\endtcolorbox
% at this point, add invisible solution
\IfSolutionPrintTF{}{%
\tcolorbox[%
    upperbox=invisible,%
    beforeafter skip = .5\baselineskip ,%
    title =
    \textbf{\GetExerciseParameter{solution-name}~\GetExerciseProperty{counter}}%
    ]%
    \GetExerciseBody{solution}%
    \endtcolorbox%
}%
}%

\DeclareExerciseEnvironmentTemplate{solution}%
{%
\tcolorbox[
    beforeafter skip = .5\baselineskip ,
    title =
    \textbf{SOL: \GetExerciseName~\GetExerciseProperty{counter}}%
    ]%
}%
{\endtcolorbox}%


\begin{document}

\section{A section title}

\begin{exercise}
    Show that $(\mathbb{R}, +, \cdot)$ is a field.
\end{exercise}

\begin{solution}
    Let $a, b, c \in \mathbb{R}$ arbitrary. Then, we show the following properties:
    \begin{description}
        \item[Commutativity of addition]  $a + b = b+ a$.
        \item[Associativity of addition] $a +(b + c) = (a+b) +c$.
        \item[Additive identity] $0 \in \mathbb{R}$, and $a +0 = a $.
        \item[Additive inverse] for each $a \in \mathbb{R}$, there exists $-a \in \mathbb{R}$, sch that $a + (-a) = 0$.
        \item[Commutativity of multiplication] $a \cdot b = b \cdot a$.
        \item[Associativity of multiplications] $a \cdot (b \dot c) = (a \cdot b) \cdot c$.
        \item[Multiplicative identity] $1 \in \mathbb{R}$, such that $1 \cdot a = a$.
        \item[Multiplicative inverse] for each $a \in \mathbb{R}$, there exists $a^{-1}\in \mathbb{R}$, such that $a \cdot a^{-1} = 1$.
        \item[Distributivity] $a\cdot (b + c) = (a \cdot b) + (a \cdot c)$.
    \end{description}
    These are the necessary and sufficient properties of a field, hence $(\mathbb{R}, +, \cdot)$ is a field.
\end{solution}
\end{document}
```

produces the outputs (dependent on the `printsolutions` property):
[image: solutions/print=true][image: solutions/print=false]

### xsim v0.20

Ideally, the same code should work. However, it does not until [this bug](https://github.com/cgnieder/xsim/issues/90) is resolved. The workaround in the issue's comments, namely using

```
\xsimsetup{collect=true}
```

and later in the document body using

```
\printcollection[print=both]{all exercises}
```

unfortunately appends a filled-in copy of the solutions if the option `solutions/print=false` is set.

So the current workaround for this answer is: Move the solution body into the exercise for printing:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath}
\usepackage[]{xsim}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\xsimsetup{
    solution/print = true,  % toggle this line
    collect=true,
}

\SetExerciseParameters{exercise}{
    exercise-name = \XSIMtranslate{exercise},
    solution-name = \XSIMtranslate{solution},
    exercise-template = exercise,
    solution-template = solution,
    counter=section,
}



\DeclareExerciseEnvironmentTemplate{exercise}
{%
\tcolorbox[
    beforeafter skip = .5\baselineskip ,
    title =
    \textbf{\GetExerciseName~\GetExerciseProperty{counter}}%
    ]%
}%
{%
\endtcolorbox
% at this point, add invisible solution
\IfSolutionPrintTF{%
\tcolorbox[%
    beforeafter skip = .5\baselineskip ,%
    title =
    \textbf{\GetExerciseParameter{solution-name}~\GetExerciseProperty{counter}}%
    ]%
    \GetExerciseBody{solution}%
    \endtcolorbox%
}{%
\tcolorbox[%
    upperbox=invisible,%
    beforeafter skip = .5\baselineskip ,%
    title =
    \textbf{\GetExerciseParameter{solution-name}~\GetExerciseProperty{counter}}%
    ]%
    \GetExerciseBody{solution}%
    \endtcolorbox%
}%
}%

\DeclareExerciseEnvironmentTemplate{solution}%
{%
\tcolorbox[
    beforeafter skip = .5\baselineskip ,
    title =
    \textbf{\GetExerciseName~\GetExerciseProperty{counter}}%
    ]%
}%
{\endtcolorbox}%


\begin{document}
\section{A section title}


\begin{exercise}
    Show that $(\mathbb{R}, +, \cdot)$ is a field.
\end{exercise}

\begin{solution}
    Let $a, b, c \in \mathbb{R}$ arbitrary. Then, we show the following properties:
    \begin{description}
        \item[Commutativity of addition]  $a + b = b+ a$.
        \item[Associativity of addition] $a +(b + c) = (a+b) +c$.
        \item[Additive identity] $0 \in \mathbb{R}$, and $a +0 = a $.
        \item[Additive inverse] for each $a \in \mathbb{R}$, there exists $-a \in \mathbb{R}$, sch that $a + (-a) = 0$.
        \item[Commutativity of multiplication] $a \cdot b = b \cdot a$.
        \item[Associativity of multiplications] $a \cdot (b \dot c) = (a \cdot b) \cdot c$.
        \item[Multiplicative identity] $1 \in \mathbb{R}$, such that $1 \cdot a = a$.
        \item[Multiplicative inverse] for each $a \in \mathbb{R}$, there exists $a^{-1}\in \mathbb{R}$, such that $a \cdot a^{-1} = 1$.
        \item[Distributivity] $a\cdot (b + c) = (a \cdot b) + (a \cdot c)$.
    \end{description}
    These are the necessary and sufficient properties of a field, hence $(\mathbb{R}, +, \cdot)$ is a field.
\end{solution}



\printcollection[print=exercises]{all exercises}
\end{document}
```

This produces the following desired output (identical to the previous version, but with less straightforward code and possible additional unobserved drawbacks):

[image: v0.20 solutions/print=true]
[image: v0.20 solutions/print=false]